# Displaying 1st column value in next column values till a not null is encountered

Tags: oracle11g

I  have table part_volume with columns part, volume_1, volume_2, volume_3, volume_4, volume_5, volume_6 columns.

Table has data like:

```
PART      VOLUME_1 VOLUME_2 VOLUME_3 VOLUME_4 VOLUME_5 VOLUME_6               
--------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
camera        1500        0        0        0     3000        0
```

I want to display data as

```
PART      VOLUME_1 VOLUME_2 VOLUME_3 VOLUME_4 VOLUME_5 VOLUME_6               
--------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
camera        1500     1500     1500     1500     3000     3000
```

How can I achieve this in oracle?

Thanks and regards,

Lopa

Answer (score 0):

so just keep the prior value if the current value is `0`?

if so:

```
select part,
       volume_1,
       coalesce(volume_2, volume_1) volume_2,
       coalesce(volume_3, volume_2, volume_1) volume_3,
       coalesce(volume_4, volume_3, volume_2, volume_1) volume_4,
       coalesce(volume_5, volume_4, volume_3, volume_2, volume_1) volume_5,
       coalesce(volume_6, volume_5, volume_4, volume_3, volume_2, volume_1) volume_6
  from (select part,
               volume_1,
               case volume_2 when 0 then to_number(null) else volume_2 end volume_2,
               case volume_3 when 0 then to_number(null) else volume_3 end volume_3,
               case volume_4 when 0 then to_number(null) else volume_4 end volume_4,
               case volume_5 when 0 then to_number(null) else volume_5 end volume_5,
               case volume_6 when 0 then to_number(null) else volume_6 end volume_6
          from data);
```

are nulls possible though and if so, is the rule the same as zero?